# Format date from string to another date format in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting date string in **20170823T075400 (YYYYMMDDThhmmss)** format from API. And I want to convert it to  **dd/MM/YY**. I am working on ionic-angular 3.5.3

Also, i have tried `var date = new Date("20170823T075400");`but getting null object.

Can anyone please help me!!!

Comment: you can use date pipe `{{ myDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy" }}` in your html page.

Comment: it works for me ... :)   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Angular here, pure javascript:

```
var dateStr = "20170823T075400";
var reg = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
var dateArr = reg.exec(dateStr); 
$scope.date = dateArr[3] + "/" + dateArr[2] + "/" + dateArr[1].substring(2, 4);
```

and you should use this pipe formate in your html

```
{{ dateObject | date:"dd/MM/yy" }}
```

*Output*:

```
23/08/17
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4cettsoo/)</kbd>

Comment: The OP want the output like **dd/MM/YY**. So I have update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
constructor(public datepipe: Datepipe){}

myfunction(){
 this.date=new Date();
 let latest_date =this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

Comment: `my function()`  is this correct syntax? and `this.date=new Date();` where is the OP input date?